# Trying to force Eigen matrices to hardcoded addresses

Tags: eigen

I've got a large Eigen-based library that runs great on Linux, but now needs to be ported to an embedded environment without a heap.

In theory this seems doable using Map, but I'd appreciate if someone could confirm my understanding of the specifics.

All the Eigen matrices are currently stored in a struct, e.g.,

```
struct {
    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> array1;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> array2;
} my_struct;

my_struct.array1 = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>::Zero(rows, cols);
my_struct.array2 = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>::Zero(rows, cols);
```

I tried using Map in the struct but that gives me assorted compile errors and I think I'm probably looking at the problem the wrong way.

So now I'm thinking I should do something like

```
struct {
    double *array1_addr;
    double *array2_addr;
} my_struct;

my_struct.array1_addr = (double *)0x100000; // address of first array
my_struct.array2_addr = (double *)0x200000; // address of second array

Eigen::Map< Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> > map1(my_struct.array1_addr, rows, cols);
map1.setZero();
Eigen::Map< Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> > map2(my_struct.array2_addr, rows, cols);
map2.setZero();
```

That is, I take the arrays all out of the struct and simply use Map to respecify the address of the array wherever I use it.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: "I tried using Map in the struct but that gives me assorted compile errors [...]" What exactly were you doing and what errors are you getting? What do you need the `struct` for in your second approach?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The struct in both approaches has a lot of ancillary data related to the Eigen matrices.  I'm just showing a bit of the struct here, but I want the struct in both cases.  What I was trying to do with the first approach was to store the Map itself in the struct, which was basically me just wrapping each matrix with Eigen::Map< >, the struct entry becoming then a Map object.  And the error I was getting was that the constructor had no arguments, which in retrospect makes sense.  It looks like there's little overhead in just reusing Map wherever I need the matrix.